# Can I get a warning before I am suspended?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderators, suspensions, quality

I have been suspended for asking too many low quality questions. They are important to me. Is there a way to check how if I am close to getting suspended again?

Comment: A little bit of hunting on the meta SE may help to get some details. Anyways, don't worry, automatic timeouts always expire with time. Note, the SE engine has no way to estimate your actual post quality, it can only measure, how well were they received (votes, flags). In my opinion, the voters tend to underestimate your posts.

Comment: @peterh "don't worry, automatic timeouts always expire with time" She was just suspended for a year.

Comment: @MitchellPorter that's not *automatic*.

Comment: @ArtOfCode well, there is the post ban which is automatic, guess the OP here meant this.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yep, but my comment was addressing Mitchell Porter's observation that the OP was suspended for a year. That's definitely not automatic.

Comment: Hi Jen, welcome back. I hope you're doing all right. Cheers!

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform i'm afraid to do something wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The algorithm for automatic low-quality suspensions is intentionally not public to avoid users gaming it, and manual suspensions (i.e. those issued by moderators and not the SE engine) rarely carry a warning with them for the same reason.

Particularly if a user already has been suspended in the past for the same behaviour, a warning is unlikely. They have already been told in the private message accompanying their last suspension what the behaviour leading to it was, and given tips on how to avoid it. Continuing the same behaviour after a suspension will inevitably lead to another, typically a longer one, without warning - the warning was the preceding suspension.

Note that there are certain behaviours for which you might receive a moderator message but not a suspension. These messages should *not* be seen as "warnings", but as messages that are sent *before* the behaviour in question reaches a level that is worthy of suspension.

This is according to general SE philosophy as laid out in [*A Day in the Penalty Box*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/).

Comment: Am i in danger?

Comment: Can I just get a question and answer ban so I can still refine my own stuff?

Comment: @Muze Whether you are "in danger" or not you can judge by asking yourself a simple question: Have you substantially changed the behaviour that led to your previous suspension?

Comment: I'm addicted I'm trying to change and ask unique mind benders as possible. I google them first but its not like here with real people.

Comment: I want to clarify that when ACuriousMind says "warning" here, he is referring to something of the form "if you do this X more times you will get suspended". We don't do that. We do, however, send mod messages saying "stop doing this", as described in the answer's third paragraph. Personally, I _would_ consider that a warning, just not the kind that gives you an ultimatum.