# What happens after being put in the penalty box twice (or more)?

Tags: support, suspensions

I've been thrown in the penalty box because I allegedly made rude comments and I had to cool down. What happens if one is thrown in the box for a second (or third, fourth...) time? Will he/she (or I) get extra punishment on top?
Is there a limit on the number of times you can be put in there?
Notice I'm not asking how the suspension time is determined. I explicitly ask what will happen after being suspended several times. Do the times you are suspended simply are added up until a limit is reached to be banned?

Comment: But I know an example of someone being permanently suspended. But you're right. I didn't read the question referred to thorowly enough.

Comment: Nothing, mods can suspend you any time for any length. CMs can suspend you network-wide, but its probability is very low, that it would ever happen. This all is being done always case by case, by our demigods. In theory, mods are accountable and all their suspension decisions is reviewed by the CMs, in practice the SE ignores the whole thing. But the possibility that they could intervene if they would want to, is already enough for the mods to think a little bit before they suspend. Mods have probably many internal disagreements, too, but ordinary mortals won't ever hear the details.

Comment: Also you have a reopen vote! Do it.

Comment: Typically, the mods do such multiple, long suspensions if they really want to eliminate someone, and they think the SE won't take care or supports them. I got twice 1 year on one of the SE sites, I don't really visit them too much since then - first, also I can not be sure, what would happen third time, and second, I think the best if I make a trophy from them on my network-wide profile, but without giving more content to them.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder A lot of instances of bans longer than a year (or for millennia in one case I know of), are done by the main SE team, and are often network-wide as far as I know.

Comment: @JMac *All* suspensions longer than a year are issued by SE staff, rather than volunteer moderators.

Comment: @rob I was going to say all; but I read some (possibly outdated) information that diamond moderators could still like delete underaged accounts and stuff; which I thought was similar enough to a permanent suspension that I didn't want to turn it into a conversation of semantics.  I failed.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica Please stop spreading false information. Moderators cannot impose suspensions longer than one year, and at least in the past the CM team has repeatedly said that they *do* audit lots of suspensions rather than "ignore the whole thing" (see e.g https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9670/50583, written by Jon when he was still a CM). You're free to not believe this, but commenting your own interpretation as fact here is highly misleading.

Comment: Since there were comments happening on both versions of this question, I've merged the two questions into one. This is why you shouldn't repost questions.

Comment: @ACuriousMind "Moderators cannot impose suspensions longer than one year" <-- Sorry I understood "any time from any length, but at most for 365 day". I tought that OP knows the 365-day limit of the mods. "CM team has repeatedly said that they do audit lots of suspensions" <-- my last 6.5 years of SE experience says its opposite.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Sorry if sometimes I appear somewhat rude to you, but that doesn't mean I don't like you. I think you have great knowledge of QFT and are able to express yourself in a clear way! This as an aside. :-)